# Bitnami lamp not giving me access to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I am trying to use bitnami lamp server and I am trying to access phpmyadmin
but I am getting nowhere for the past 1 hour trying to access it.
Here is the error I am getting.
[image]

in my apache2 conf / httpd.conf file I have ServerName URL:80 
and i am using SSH tunnel through putty by following this link https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the command `ls -lahrt /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`? It seems that, perhaps, apache is not able to do anything with that socket because permissions got screwed up. Will be looking forward to an aswer! :)

Comment: @DavidGonzalez actually the person was screwed up, I allowed any person to access it and it was all fine. Sorry for the late reply!!

Answer (score 0):

Check mysql's default port...the port number is 3306

Answer (score 0):

As specified in a subcomment, the issue is due to wrong permissions in the socket file of the DB. You can check them with:

`ls -lahrt /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`